# As a moderator, I can't tell which questions on a user's profile on Mi Yodeya are deleted

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-tools, profile-page

As a moderator on Mi Yodeya, I can see deleted answers on any user profile and I see all the questions, but the deleted questions are not visually distinguished.  I would like to be able to see at a glance which of a user's questions are deleted, just as I can for answers.  Can we get the same red-background treatment for questions, or, failing that, a textual note like "[deleted]"?  This would be very helpful when reviewing the activities of users who are close to suspension.

This screen shot is from my own profile page (so I'm not revealing deleted questions of anybody without permission).  The first question is not deleted; the following four are.

[image: screen shot from Mi Yodeya]

Comment: It already does this for me on [android.se]...the bottom 4 questions on this (semi-redacted) screenshot of another user's profile are deleted: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16947730/DeletedQuestions.png

Comment: Huh.  Not the case for me on Mi Yodeya.  Maybe it's specific to us?

Comment: Could be some kind of weird CSS bug, maybe? I can't really think of an intentional reason for one site to see it differently than another.

Comment: It's always been this way for me, across multiple browsers and operating systems, for what that's worth.

Comment: Yeah, this is just a CSS issue. (Or at least I can repro it on Mi Yodeya in Chrome on Windows 7.) As a moderator, you do see deleted questions in everyone's profile, but they are currently impossible to distinguish them from the rest. (On other sites, they have a different background to set them apart.)

Comment: In such case isn't this question better be migrated to the relevant meta site?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, no objections from me.  When I asked I hadn't realized it was specific to us, which is why I asked here on MSO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, > rev 2013.4.1.595.

Comment: Thanks!  Fixed now.

Comment: This bug came back when the new CSS reached our site ([report](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3770/472)).  Are you still the right person to ask about this?

Comment: @MonicaCellio k, I've checked a fix in again for this (and I commented it!), so hopefully it won't happen again.  Will roll out sometime today.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  Commenting is good. :-)