# Site Design Updates are Live

Tags: discussion, design

A majority of the changes are not visible; these tweaks go along with recent updates that were made to Stack Overflow:

- We have updated the site's CSS to a newly refactored LESS system, so that it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally and launch new features in the future.
- We've updated most of the graphics to SVG for retina support.
- We've fixed a LOT of obscure bugs that arose when new features were not thoroughly tested across the entire network.
- Plus, we launched the new user profile.

Visually it should "feel" the same as the old site with slight layout adjustments.

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old design bugs. If you see any new bugs, or old ones not yet fixed, please post an answer here to let us know!

Comment: Excellent news!  I've been looking forward to the new profile for months.

Comment: Re "old [bugs] not yet fixed", users may want to check [this list](/search?q=[bug]+-[status-completed]+[design]+-[status-declined]+is%3Aq+closed%3A0) and [this one](/search?q=[bug]+-[status-completed]+[display]+-[status-declined]+is%3Aq+closed%3A0).

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for the 404 and error pages.

Comment: @msh210 you're welcome. Thanks for making the community awesome!

Comment: Excellent work. I can't even tell it's changed! (that's a good thing)

Comment: @KurtisBeavers is this post still the right place to post [bug reports](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3770/472)?

Answer (score 4):

Not a bug but a request:

[image: gray new-posts bar]

In the old design that gray bar was a light cream color, similar to the events block at right.  (I think it was a little lighter -- maybe the color of post notices?)  That color fit in better with the other warm colors on the site, to my eye; the gray clashes a bit.  Is this color available for customization?  If so, would you consider adjusting it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The bug reported [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1595/759) is back.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Chrome and Windows 8. I'm definitely not seeing it on deleted questions in profiles.

Comment: I am now seeing this bug too (and was coming here to report it, having forgotten that you did).  Chrome and Firefox, questions only (I see the pink background on deleted answers), Mac (10.6).

Comment: This has been [fixed again](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1595/as-a-moderator-i-cant-tell-which-questions-on-a-users-profile-on-mi-yodeya-ar/1596#comment11826_1596).

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Completely borked "You earned a new privilege!" text with anything going below it:

> [image]

For example, that's how the "correct version" looks on Skeptics:

> [image]

Comment: A fix is on the way.

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The buttons are flickering on hover, disturbs a bit:

> [image]

Comment: A fix is on the way.

Answer (score 0):

[Supposedly](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/244889), when I go to someone's user page (not my own), I should be seeing his Profile tab by default. Instead, I see his Activity tab by default. Seemingly this is a bug; otherwise, consider this a feature request for a persistent tab choice (like we have for [`/questions`](/questions)).

Comment: That's because you're a moderator.  If you try it on another site you'll see the Profile view.  (If this is happening to somebody who isn't a mod, please tell us.)